# Resetting the Counter of LineNumberReader

Tags: java, file-io

I'm reading contents of the Spool.txt and writing it to a 77 line text file based on the codes of the first four columns.

- 005 means writing to Line 5
- Subsequent 1 means writing to the next line
- 2 means writing to the next second line
- 3 means writing to the next third line

The issue is when I tried to write to Line 37 of the output file, it continues from the counter of the last line written. I like to write to Line 37 starting from the beginning of the file.

I'm using `LineNumberReader` to keep track of the number of lines I write to a text file. I understand that `setLineNumber(int)` does not actually not change the current position of the text file. How do I reset the counter so I can write to a specific line from the start of the file?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{   
    File f= new File("file1.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Spool.txt"));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        lines.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    String[] arrLine = lines.toArray(new String[0]);

    //System.out.println(arrLine[1]);

    for (int i=0;i<arrLine.length;i++)
    {
        String s1=arrLine[i].toString();
        String s2= s1.substring(0,4);

        if (s2.trim().equals("005"))
        {
            try 
            {
                lnr.setLineNumber(4);
                for(int j=1;j<=lnr.getLineNumber();j++)
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(arrLine[i]);   
             } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
            else if (s2.trim().equals("1"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    lnr.setLineNumber(1);
                    for(int j=1;j<=lnr.getLineNumber();j++)                 
                        bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(arrLine[i]);
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if (s2.trim().equals("2"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    lnr.setLineNumber(2);
                    for(int j=1;j<=lnr.getLineNumber();j++)
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(arrLine[i]);
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if (s2.trim().equals("3"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    lnr.setLineNumber(3);   
                    for(int j=1;j<=lnr.getLineNumber();j++)
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(arrLine[i]);   
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } // END Else If Loop

            else if (s2.trim().equals("37"))    **//ISSUE STARTS HERE: I'm trying to write to Line 37 counting from the start of the file again. It is writing to Line 37 starting from the previous lines written above**
            {
                try 
                {
                    lnr.setLineNumber(37);  
                    for(int j=1;j<=lnr.getLineNumber();j++)
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(arrLine[i]);   
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } // END Else If Loop

        }
        bw.close();
        lnr.close();                
    }   //main
}   //class
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can't insert into the text file. I would suggest another approach.
You open one file for reading `Spool.txt` and another file for writing `Spool.txt.write` then you read from your first file analyze each line and write to another file. Once you complete everything, just remove `Spool.txt` and rename `Spool.txt.write` to `Spool.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the file in a random access mode, which needs another classes to open it. And even with that, it will not allow you to *insert*, random access mode are well suited for replacing (and you need to control the size of each element).

A better alternative is, before writting to file, put each line in an array with the index as the line number. Once all the lines are there, iterate the array and write the lines in order.